# EXCEL - Count number of times a value is the max of its category

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the total number of times the search term (B2) is the maximum for each column.
For example, I can visually tell that `row4` is the maximum in three different columns. However, my goal is to get this result with a formula for cases where there may be too many categories to manually count.

|  | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 0.00% | 0.15% | 0.00% | 0.04% | 0.01% | 0.08% |
| row2 | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.04% | 0.00% | 823.45% |
| row3 | 2.45% | 0.98% | 0.29% | 1.45% | 0.24% | 0.66% |
| row4 | 14.04% | 4.97% | 12.02% | 10.32% | 13.76% | 6.31% |
| row5 | 0.00% | 0.00% | 0.12% | 15.23% | 0.11% | 0.00% |
| row6 | 1.71% | 5.12% | 2.75% | 0.98% | 1.02% | 1.34% |

***Without added rows***
[image: Without added rows]

I can do this fairly easily if I were to add another row, but my hope is to do it without this step.

***With added row***
[image: With added row]

Formulas used in the added rows:

`=INDEX($D$3:$D$8,MATCH(MAX(E13:E18),E13:E18,0))`

`=COUNTIF(E19:J19,B12)`

My guess is that I will need to use some type of sum/sumif function in order to add 1 for each occurrence of a column max, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I can return a boolean of 1 or 0 for a single occurrence, but I'm struggling to make it work through each column individually. For a single column, `=IF(XLOOKUP(B2,D3:D8,E3:E8)>=MAX(E3:E8),"1","0")` is working to set it to either 1 or 0 depending on if the search term is greater than or equal to the max. If I can make this formula work for each column, then sum it up, I believe it would work. Maybe an array is needed?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your screenshot of data is not useful. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful please edit your question to post it as ***text***, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, since this is not a free code-writing service, please add what you have tried to your question.

Comment: I have edited with a markdown table of the example data-- the actual data itself is just filler data to use as an example. I have tried each of the formulas listed in the original question, but am struggling to find the path to take those from single-column results to multi-column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can use:

```
=SUM(--(A2=INDEX(myTbl[row],BYCOL(myTbl[[column1]:[column6]],LAMBDA(array,MATCH(MAX(array),array,0))))))
```

where A2 contains the name in the "row" column, this formula will return the number of columns where that row is MAX.

[image]

Comment: That worked great, thank you! I will have to dig into it to understand how exactly it works.